# Backup and restore CM10 on broken razr

Tags: cyanogenmod, backup, factory-reset, stock-android, motorola-droid-razr

My problem is a little bit complicated, I have a Razr (XT910) motorola phone, the screen is cracked and unusable, the tech support of my carrier (in Mexico) is unable to get the display from motorola...

However, what I want to do (since I need a phone...) is sell the broken display phone I have on eBay (since Motorola USA has the display) so the buyer can repair it and have a "cheap" razr, and I can buy a phone also in eBay or here in Mexico.

But to do so, I need to factory reset the phone (and if possible get my information backed up), but since the screen is cracked I don't know how to do so (The phone receives calls, and maybe the touchscreen is functional, but I'm not sure).

The specific details of my phone:

It's rooted, it has safestrap 2.x installed, it has the ICS stock rom, and CM10 (beta).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/) to see the screen on a computer.

Since you have stock ICS, Droid@screen should be enough to boot into stock, remove the CM10 install and/or do a factory reset.

Comment: It is currently booted in CM10, would it still work? (I can't try it now because my phone is with tech support, but I can get it tomorrow to test possibly).

Comment: No, you'd have to boot into stock for a factory reset. How do you switch between CM and stock when the screen works?