# Ways of unlocking Nexus 4 cracked touch screen

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, nexus-4, touchscreen, remote-control, pattern-lock

If anyone could give me some ideas on where i should start with my cracked Nexus 4? I'm trying to pattern unlock, so I can simply access to back-up my important data. I can see the screen, even answer calls but that's it! I figured their has to be a way around the touch screen interface well actually I'm preying there is.

If you know software, a physical device, internet remote, something anything that will allow me to use my phone for temporarily command please let me know ASAP id greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Several related readings: [Cannot unlock tablet as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) (though it's a little different cause), [Backup and restore CM10 on broken razr](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36280/16575), [Backup apps on SGS 2 with broken display?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51629/16575), [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575), [more](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=backup+broken+screen+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use a usb-to-go cable to connect a mouse and get into the phone that way.  I'm running Cyanogenmod though.  Not sure if the mouse will work with stock android.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2415195

Read this guide http://forum.xda-developers.com/show....php?t=2266654 . only follow the parts to unlock the boot loader and flash clockworkmod custom recovery. Make sure that you flash the recovery right after unlocking (without rebooting in between) otherwise data will get wiped. )

After that boot into your newly flashed recovery and use "adb pull /data/media/" . this should copy everything on the internal sdcard of the phone.

Comment: Doesn't the unlocking procedure wipe everything? Have you tried this?

Answer (score -1):

I know that Revskills has an entire remote control interface on the computer screen. It's available for download for free with a full license by the author himself- just do a google search for "revskills download free" or some such. It's a forensic program, so it's made for this kind of thing.

Answer (score -2):

Wakeup touch nexus was the best that i found!! Works great on my nexus 4.

Comment: A link to the software you're recommending would make this answer useful.