# Access phone from computer without passcode

Tags: nexus-4, touchscreen, password, broken-screen

I just shattered the screen of my Nexus 4 (sigh...) and am unable to use the touch screen. However getting it fixed costs more than just buying a new phone so I would like to access my data, transfer it on my PC and get a new phone.

There's just a problem: when I plug in the phone to my computer it requires me to unlock it and I can't because of the broken screen.

Does anyone know about software I can use to access it or any solution that will allow me to copy my data?

Comment: See: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54439/ways-of-unlocking-nexus-4-cracked-touch-screen

Comment: Exactly what is broken: can the screen still display, or register touches, or neither?

Comment: @DanHulme - the operating system seems to work fine and the screen is displayed perfectly (just cracked in a part). The problem is that half of the touch is not working (and there's not even a crack in the part not working)

Answer (score 1):

You can try few links I am giving you here and if you are really worried much about all your data,then go to data recovery specialist and get data recovered.

- http://computersaremylife.wordpress.com/2013/09/15/broken-android-touch-screen-cant-unlock-solution/
- http://android-commander.en.lo4d.com/
- http://www.fosshub.com/MyPhoneExplorer.html
- https://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Most of these required 'adb and USB connection' enabled.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the links die. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).